# Edit AirPort Extreme settings Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, airport, raspberry-pi, airport-extreme

I'm using a raspberry pi as a sort of network login (ssh, VPN, nas access) for when I'm not at home. I have an AirPort Extreme router. Is there a way of changing the routers settings from the raspberry pi? Not its headless, ie I wans to change the settings in terminal on the raspberry pi using ssh.

I have tried airport-utile package, but it requires X11, and I can't set up VNC (For non-tech related reasons)

Any way I can do this? Thanks for your help

PS the Raspberry pi is running the standard Raspbian image

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to identify what ports the APE is using for its configuration utility then forward them through an SSH tunnel, running the Configuration Utility on your Macbook or PC.